# Save file path according to worker matric number vba

Tags: excel, vba, path

I would like to save file in a "CONSOLIDATE FOLDER". But the file path should depend on staff working number ID (00639) where they input it in the "TEMPLATE" worksheet cell "N3". And in case staff forgot to input their working ID, there'll be a pop up box telling them to fill in their ID.

Any help really appreciated.

```
Sub MergeFile ()

Dim WB As Workbook 
Dim WS as Worksheet
Dim FileName as String
Dim FilePath as String

Set WB = Workbook.Add
FilePath = "C:\Users\KGA00639\Desktop\CONSOLIDATE FOLDER"
FileName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("L15").Value

For Each WS in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WS.Name <> "TEMPLATE" Then
    WS.Copy before:=WB.Sheets(1)
End if
If FileName = "" Then
FileName = InputBox ("You did not name the workbook" & vbCrLf & _
"Please write the name and press OK.:,"Setting the workbook name")
If FileName = "" Then Exit sub
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("L15").Value = FileName
End If

Next

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName 
MsgBox ("Done"!)
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: What cell is the user ID supposed to be in?

Comment: Also you didn't set `WB` to be anything

Comment: Do you really need the user's ID in the template? Couldn't you use this code instead? `FilePath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\CONSOLIDATE FOLDER"` where the user's name is taken from the ENVIRON object?

Comment: sorry. I just edit the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution should come rather close to what you want. Please take a look.

```
Sub MergeFile()
    ' 056

    Dim Wb          As Workbook
    Dim Ws          As Worksheet
    Dim FileName    As String
    Dim FilePath    As String
    Dim UserID      As String
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMPLATE")
        UserID = .Cells(1, "A").Value               ' change address to suit
        FileName = .Range("L15").Value
        If Left(UserID, 2) <> "ID" Then
            MsgBox "You must enter your valid user ID in" & vbCr & _
                   "cell A1 of the 'Template' tab." & vbCr & _
                   "This program will now be terminated.", _
                   vbInformation, "Incomplete preparation"
            .Activate
            .Cells(1, "A").Select                   ' change to match above
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' use the UserID variable in whichever way you wish
    FilePath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\" & UserID & "\Desktop\CONSOLIDATE FOLDER"
    
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Add
    For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Ws.Name <> "TEMPLATE" Then
            Ws.Copy Before:=Wb.Sheets(1)
        End If
    Next Ws
    Wb.SaveAs FilePath & FileName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You didn't specify where on the 'Template' tab the user ID would be found. The above code looks for it in cell A1. That cell is mentioned in 3 locations in the code (once in the message text). Please modify the code to match your facts.

You also didn't say where the UserID should appear in the FilePath. I placed it before the Desktop. I'm sure you will know how to amend that bit of code to suit you better.

When saving the workbook my code specifies an xlsx format. If this isn't what you want change the file format constant in the `SaveAs` line. I didn't think it a good idea to specify the extension in the 'Template'. You may like to move it to the code.

Finally, you didn't specify the next step after creation of the new workbook. So the code ends in the middle of nowhere. Excel made the new workbook the active one but you may like to close it, or ThisWorkbook, and determine what to do with the blank worksheet(s) still contained in the new book. There are a lot of lose ends still to tidy up. Good luck!

Comment: thank you @Variatus . Sorry for my incomplete code. I incorporated your code into mine and its works well. Thanks again